# Create raster layer from point layer attribute with point layer boundary

Tags: qgis

I want to create raster layer using point layer and having its attribute as Z value for Raster and need raster to follow boundary of point layer 
Point layer has sampling at 100m distance so I want raster to follow boundary of point layer + 100meters.

How can I perform this task in QGIS

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

In the *Metadata* tab (of `layer property`) you can find extent of the point layer as *(xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax)*. Based on this information create a larger grid (expanded to each side).

[image]

Start *Interpolation* (from the menu `Raster | Interpolation | Interpolation`) and give wider extent to the output raster. (In this example = 4900, 4900, 5300, 5300).

[image]

Output would be something like this. This interpolation result was terrible, though.

[image]